# Google sheets - script editor Data validation builder - format filtered date list

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatdatetime

I am using "filter" method in script editor to filter a range and obtain list of all values in the second column of the filtered range. `plSentDateValidationList` contains list of dates and is fed as an input into data validation builder with "requireValueInList" method.

```
// Get DC dates using FILTER
      var plSentDateList = PSIData.filter(function(item){
        return item[0] === miDC; 
      })
      
      var plSentDateValidationList = plSentDateList.map(x => x[1]).sort();     
     
      //Logger.log(plSentDateValidationList);     

      var plSentDateValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(plSentDateValidationList).setAllowInvalid(false).build();      
      
      // Apply validation rule to adjacent cell using offset
      activeCell.offset(0,1).setDataValidation(plSentDateValidationRule);
```

Everything works as expected, however, the dates from the filter output are long version of date. The logger output of variable `plSentDateValidationList` is:

```
Info    [Tue Mar 02 13:30:00 GMT-05:00 2021, Tue Mar 02 13:30:00 GMT-05:00 2021]
```

However, I want this to be formatted as "dd/mm/yyyy" so that the resulting dropdown from data validation list is concise.

I have tried `Utilities.formatDate()` method without much luck. I think I am missing something simple here. How do I format the list `plSentDateValidationList` output `[Tue Mar 02 13:30:00 GMT-05:00 2021, Tue Mar 02 13:30:00 GMT-05:00 2021]` to `dd/mm/yyyy` format and then use list of these formatted dates into the data validation builder?

**Note: the spreadsheet settings "locale" is set to United Kingdom and Timezone is set to GMT+5:30**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
var plSentDateValidationList = plSentDateList.map(x => x[1]).sort().map(x => Utilities.formatDate(x, 'BST', 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
```

Comment: Thanks! There was a wierd behaviour with month formatting. If the correct output was `03/03/2021`, I was actually getting `03/30/2021`. I fixed this by changing the date format string from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `dd/MM/yyyy`.  Is 'BST' = British standard time?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should be `'dd/MM/yyyy'`, sorry for my typo. Also, I think the your timezone should be `IST`? Please check my updated answer.